# Using RestSharp, how do I load returned JSON data into variables that I can access

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2013, restsharp

I am new to visual studio. Currently I am using RestSharp to access an api that returns data in JSON format. My question is, how can I loop through the returned data and assign the values to variables that I can then display on my view.

I have set up the connection to the API and I can dump the returned value to an asp:literal.

Here is the code that handles that.

```
private void GetApiDataViaRestSharp()
    {
        var client = new RestClient
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(USERNAME, PASSWORD),
            BaseUrl = API_ENDPOINT
        };

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
        {
            Resource = "Contact/{ContactId}"
        };
        request.AddUrlSegment("ContactId", CONTACT_TO_LOOKUP);

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var contentBody = response.Content;

        lit1.Text = contentBody;


    }
```

Where do I go next?

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Use:

```
var response = client.Execute<SomeResultType>(request);
...
var responseData = response.Data;
```

Where 'SomeResultType' is a class you've written that fits the expected shape of the JSON to be loaded.

Comment: So I added a class Contact.cs that defines the variables that I need. Modified the code with your suggestions.
    var response = client.Execute<Contact>(request);
    var responseData = response.Data;
How can I set the value of lit1 to one of the variables? lit1.Text =